# Prevent deletion of checkbox in sheet editable by many users

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

I am using checkboxes in a sheet (and their functionality in themselves are exactly what I need).

The problems I am having is that the users who are able to edit the sheet, sometime (by mistake) delete the checkbox instead of simply checking/un-checking the checkbox.

Hence, I want the users to use the checkboxes, but not be able to delete them.

Is this possible somehow?

FYI: it is not possible to use Google Forms in the case.

Comment: if so, then only with script that would check if cell contains a checkbox and if not it would add one

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This script would have to be invoked as soon as something is changed in the sheet, right? How is that possible?

Comment: there is onOpen or onEdit trigger for that

Comment: You'll want to read up on Triggers (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example on how to achive it using [onOpen triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene)

```js
function onOpen(e) 
{
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange(1,4,5);
  var values = range.getValues();

  for ( var val in values ) {
    if( values[val] != true && values[val] != false ) {
      values[val]= false;
    }
  }

  range.insertCheckboxes(values);
}
```

You have to specify where are the checkboxes placed, in the code example provided there are 5 of them, starting from row 1 to row 5, and they are placed on the 4th column, so called D.

This is specified on the getRange(1,4,5) function:

`getRange(InitialRow, Initial Column, Number of Rows)`

for more documentation around the use of getRange() use the following [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows).

This onOpen function will be executed every time that the spreadsheet is opened, and if on the specified fields there aren't `false` or `true` statements, it means that we lost the checkbox somehow, so it will introduce them again.