# How to create onEdit function with insertCheckboxes and TRUE/FALSE?

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

In `Z6` there is a formula: `if the checkbox in E6 = TRUE (i.e. checked) then 'X' else 'Y'`. This works fine. Unfortunatly some users by mistake delete the checkbox and hence I need to implement a logic to add it back. I am attempting to implement [the logic as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997474/prevent-deletion-of-checkbox-in-sheet-editable-by-many-users/59354450#59354450) but as `onEdit`. I dont really know what I'm doing so suggestions are VERY welcome:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rangeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRangeList(['E6:E7']);
  for (var i=0; i<rangeList.getRanges().length; i++ ) {
    var range = rangeList.getRanges()[i];
    for (var j=0; j<range.getValues().length; j++ ) {
      var value = range.getValue()[j];
      Logger.log("i: " + i);
      Logger.log("j: " + j);
      Logger.log("value: " + value);
      var values = range.getValues();
      for ( var val in values ) {
        Logger.log("values[val]: " + values[val]);
        if( values[val] != 'TRUE' && values[val] != 'FALSE' ) {
          range.insertCheckboxes('TRUE', 'FALSE');
          Logger.log("arrived at insert checkbox");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`E6:E7` is just the first range (about 30 in total). It does as it is supposed to, BUT before the `onEdit` is executed for the first time, the following formula `=WENN(E7=FALSE();"is false";E7)` shows `is false`. BUT once the script has been run the result of the formula is `FALSE`. Thus, before I activate above `onEdit` function the formula `=WENN(E7=FALSE();"is false";E7)` shows `is false`.

Once I activate above `onEdit` function it does not matter what cell I change, the result of the formula switches to `FALSE`. Here is the log protocol for that intial run changing any cell but `E6:E7`:

```
[20-01-07 15:11:33:557 CET] i: 0
[20-01-07 15:11:33:558 CET] j: 0
[20-01-07 15:11:33:558 CET] value: F
[20-01-07 15:11:33:559 CET] values[val]: FALSE
[20-01-07 15:11:33:559 CET] values[val]: TRUE
[20-01-07 15:11:33:560 CET] i: 0
[20-01-07 15:11:33:560 CET] j: 1
[20-01-07 15:11:33:560 CET] value: A
[20-01-07 15:11:33:561 CET] values[val]: FALSE
[20-01-07 15:11:33:561 CET] values[val]: TRUE
```

Similarly, the following formulas for cells `H6` and `H7` :

- `=WENN(H6=FALSE();"is false";H6)` shows `is false`.
- `=WENN(H7=FALSE();"is false";H7)` shows `is false`.

Here is the log from when I perform the action of copying `H6:H7` into the cells `E6:E7`:

```
[20-01-07 06:01:50:720 PST] i: 0
[20-01-07 06:01:50:720 PST] j: 0
[20-01-07 06:01:50:721 PST] value: undefined
[20-01-07 06:01:50:722 PST] values[val]: false
[20-01-07 06:01:50:897 PST] arrived at insert checkbox
[20-01-07 06:01:50:898 PST] values[val]: true
[20-01-07 06:01:51:041 PST] arrived at insert checkbox
[20-01-07 06:01:51:168 PST] i: 0
[20-01-07 06:01:51:168 PST] j: 1
[20-01-07 06:01:51:169 PST] value: A
[20-01-07 06:01:51:170 PST] values[val]: FALSE
[20-01-07 06:01:51:170 PST] values[val]: TRUE
```

Again in the end the formula `=WENN(E7=FALSE();"is false";E7)` shows `FALSE`.

What I need is that after a deleted checkbox has been re-created by the `onEdit` function, the formula `=WENN(E7=FALSE();"is false";E7)` shows `is FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that, when you create the checkbox, you provide strings `TRUE` and `FALSE` as custom values for checked and unchecked states, and the string `FALSE` is not the same as the logical value returned in `FALSE()`.

If you don't provide custom values to the [insertCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcheckboxes), the default checked/unchecked values are boolean `true` and `false` which, in this last case, matches the value returned by the built-in function [FALSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093302?hl=en). So the output is "is false" when the checkbox is unchecked.

So please try removing the custom values. That is, try replacing this:

```js
range.insertCheckboxes('TRUE', 'FALSE');
```

For this:

```js
range.insertCheckboxes();
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Indeed it did help. Thank you so much. Having added all the other ranges I now a performance problem, but I will open another question for that.

Comment: @mortpiedra glad it helped. Also, because your original question was solved, please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.